# Can not create XML in one method and then append child nodes in another method

Tags: c#, xml

I have following code I want to use:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlDeclaration xmlDeclaration = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
        XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
        doc.InsertBefore(xmlDeclaration, root);
        WriteXmlFile("PartNew", doc);
    }

    public static void WriteXmlFile(string nextItem, XmlDocument doc)
    {
        XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
        XmlElement id = doc.CreateElement(nextItem);
        id.SetAttribute("Part", nextItem);
        doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(id);
        root.AppendChild(id);
    }
```

The problem is that I am getting an error message saying that my DocumentElement is null. This is the line where I get the error message `doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(id);`. I googled but I didn't find any similar case I have. What do I miss to get my code running?

Error message:

> NullReferenceException on object DocumentElement

Comment: Try load method :             StringReader reader = new StringReader(nextItem);
            doc.Load(reader);

Comment: In your Main method you create an `XmlDocument` object, but that object is still nothing. It does not have a document element. You could have a basic "outline" of your xml as string like this: `<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><root></root>` and after `new XmlDocument();` use `doc.LoadXml(` to load this string into your doc object. THEN you would have a document element to work with.

Comment: Side note but if you do this a lot you will be so much happier with XDocument et al.

Answer (score 2):

You do not create a root element.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNode rootNode = doc.CreateElement("root");
doc.AppendChild(rootNode);
```

Comment: Thanks Klaus Gütter, such simple and it´s working fine - Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using XmlDocument and all those manipulations with adding XML declarations, you could use LINQ-aware [XDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument):

```
var xml = new XDocument(
    new XDeclaration("1.0","utf-8", "yes"),
    new XElement("root",
        new XElement("PartNew", new XAttribute("Part", "1"))));

Console.WriteLine(xml.Declaration.ToString() + "\n" + xml.ToString());
```

Output:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
  <PartNew Part="1" />
</root>`

You can apply LINQ to create elements:

```
var xml2 = new XDocument(
    new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
    new XElement("root",
        from x in new[] {1, 2, 3}
        select new XElement("PartNew", new XAttribute("Part", x))));

Console.WriteLine(xml2.Declaration.ToString() + "\n" + xml2.ToString());
```

Output:

`<root>
  <PartNew Part="1" />
  <PartNew Part="2" />
  <PartNew Part="3" />
</root>`